# PHP system() args

Tags: php, c++, system, executable, exec

I have the following code that executes a **C++ program** and **outputs it**:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>C++</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div><?php 
    system("app.exe", $out);
    echo rtrim($out, "0");
     ?></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I make it so that **you can pass arguments to the c++ program**, say like this...

If this was the **c++** program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main(){
  string input = getarg();//Not really a function, just one I kinda want to know
  cout << input;
  return 0;
}
```

**Could I do something like this?**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>C++</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div><?php 
    system("app.exe arg=hello-world", $out);
    echo rtrim($out, "0");
     ?></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I **don't know** a lot of parts to  this problem, **I can execute the program** but I just **need to pass arguments.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the arguments space separated after the command like
    `system("app.exe hello-world 2 3", $out);`

in your c++ program

```
 int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    // argv[1] will be pointing to "hello-world"
    // argv[2] => 2
    // argv[3] => 3 
 }
```

Comment: probably should use `escapeshellarg()` if the arguments come from a user - http://php.net/escapeshellarg