# PHP system batch args

Tags: php, batch-file, arguments, system

Using **PHP's** [`system`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) function, how can you **pass arguments to a batch file?**

It would probably look something like this

`system("batch.bat argument", $output);`

I found out how to do it with a **C++ executable** [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640414/php-system-args)

I'm guessing it should be relatively simple...

What the real question is is how to receive the argument with a batch file?

Comment: Exactly how you've written. Is there a problem with that?

Comment: No, how do you RECIEVE the argument with the batch file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, there is no difference. Here is a small demo:

First a batch file to just output its arguments:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\SO>type a.bat
@echo off
echo %*
```

A php program that uses `system` to invoke the batch file passing `a` and `b` as args:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\SO>type a.php
<?php
    system("a.bat a b",$out);
?>
```

On running the php, the call to `system` invokes the bat file with `a` and `b` as arguments, the batch file runs and echoes `a` and `b`

```
C:\Documents and Settings\SO>php a.php
a b
```

Comment: In the program I've used `%*` to access them all together.

Answer (score 2):

Arguments in batch file are accessible as %1 %2 etc...

http://www.hccp.org/bat-cmd-line-args.html

http://www.rgagnon.com/gp/gp-0009.html